# TeX editor with instant preview

Tags: reference-request, math-software

I'm looking for a TeX editor with instant preview just has we have here on MSE.

I tried asking the folks at TeX Exchange, but they were no help at all, so don't bother migrating or whatever. If this question is inappropiate here, just close it, please.

Comment: A long time ago I found an editor with this tool, but it was very very pour editor. I suggest you to use `texmaker` and you can jut hit one key to compile and open the output. Nowadays the computers can do this very fast especially with simple documents.

Comment: @Sigur To be honest that's not good enough.

Comment: No. This is one of the reason to TeX to be so good.

Comment: @Sigur How is it good to not have something? If you don't want it, you can disable it.

Comment: @GitGud: The tools to create something better if you think that would be worth the effort are available to you freely on the internet. Have fun.

Comment: Here is one, and online, plus: https://www.writelatex.com/

Comment: I wondered why there never was such a preview aswell. TeXStudio has a instant preview of math formulas when you hover over them.

Comment: After using TeX in the right way you'll discover that this is not so useful. Please, try to type in TeX as well as you should.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles Is that edit supposed to somehow imply they actually helped me? Because they obviously didn't. Poor answers or suggestions that didn't work.

Comment: @GitGud: I have edited what I found to be an unnecessarily rude comment. Please try to stay constructive.

Comment: @GitGud: They didn't help you because your question was about MathJax, not TeX, and therefore off-topic on their site. Your insults are unwarranted.

Comment: @ZevChonoles How was my comment rude? And clearly Sigur didn't feel any animosity coming from me.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Asking about a TeX editor is not about TeX? Maybe you're right, it might be MetaTeX....

Comment: Peace and love, guys.

Comment: I tried writelatex.com  It seems to fail in Firefox, but worked in Explorer.  It took a while to render.

Comment: I'll follow julien on [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/). The update is a little delayed (so no slowdown of input by output!) and some things like tags and links will not work for SE but it looks pretty good (in Safari and possibly Webkit on iPad).

Comment: @GitGud I am writing an app for you real quick. Bear with me for 10 minutes

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm with Google Chrome and it works pretty well.

Comment: @GitGud done ;) You need the .Net 4.0 redistutable if you are working on windows, as that is the only OS my program works on

Comment: You can also see "TexStudio".

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh I tried TeXStudio, couldn't get any sort of instant preview to work. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @GitGud, Yes I have it now, and I use it, and texmaker and winedit too. In texstudio from main menu click on "Options" then select "Configure Texstudio", then from new window that is opened select tab "Build", then in front of "PDF Viewer", select "Internal PDF Viewer(Embedded)". then you can see your pdf inside. But it's not instant preview in same time, you should run to see changes in left side pdf.

Comment: Folks, actually there is Windows Version of Gummi. I am using it. and It's not as instant as Math.SE, nor as good, but an unstable, test version for Windows is developed. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi GitGud, off topic but you have a totally awesome picture for your profile! Mind if I use it on my blog?

Comment: @Joao It's freely available on the web (e.g. [here](https://warosu.org/data/lit/img/0048/08/1398324955556.jpg)), so you have every right to use it and I don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

It's not precisely TeX, but you can use MathJax in an HTML file on your hard drive, in conjunction with a text editor and web browser. Here is a stub page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({ tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$']] } });</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
</head>
<body>
$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like a lot of trouble. I just want to open an editor, type and save, that's it.

Comment: Actually it's an order of magnitude less trouble than using any conventional TeX compiler. Maybe you should actually try it.

Comment: And writing a Python program to convert this to regular latex is not too hard.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Mathb.in](http://mathb.in) from time to time (you can even save the posts you create and link to them, just like pastebin). <s>Maybe you should rather ask in the TeX.SE however</s> ;)

[I hacked a quick C# GUI that uses MathJax](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13337387/LaTeXRender.exe) (needs online connection right now, maybe I can change that. Not today however). Have fun!

---

I can't answer it anymore because it's closed, then I'll borrow some space in your answer CBenni.

- [latexlab.org](http://docs.latexlab.org/) is nice, it has integration with google docs, you'll just need to click the *split* button to work with the screen divided  between code and preview. It has also the benefit of being free.
- [sharelatex.com](https://www.sharelatex.com) is also cool, but it's [with the free version, you'll have little privileges.](https://www.sharelatex.com/user/subscription/plans)

Comment: The latexrender.exe link you gave shows error 404.

Comment: @Moronplusplus I have probably deleted that file off the server, I can reupload it if you like.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi) is a solution. Enjoy it.

**ps:** if you don't use Linux, sorry. You have to pay the price to use Windows.

[image]

Comment: I don't use linux. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GitGud. So it's time to start using. You'll love it.

Comment: I don't use linux because lots of software I use don't work there.

Comment: Doing a windoze install of linux is easy.  you will start using it and soon you will forget Windoze.

Comment: @ncmathsadist, you mean all windows software can be used in Linux too. If it will be true it's a good news! please describe how. I like to know. Untill now I had used only windows.

Comment: It can be. Get an Ubuntu DVD and learn about doing a Windoze install. It's quick and easy and it gives you a chance to try Linux without reformatting or doing anything risky.